# grouping name in sharepoint 2010 using sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I made quiz application in `sharepoint 2010` using `sharepoint designer 2010`. every user can follow this application everytime. after they follow quiz application, their name will displayed in List Answer.

For example: user B follow 5 times this quiz, automatically her name will displayed in List Answer 5 times. But, i just want to display user B 1 time not 5 times. so, although user B follow 5 or 10 times quiz, her name just displayed 1 times in List Answer.

Could you help me, please
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a list to Store the results?

If yes, then you can generate a view with group by option .

SO it will  display name of user above only once not multiple times.

Let me correct if I understand your problem wrong